# 2 separable O.D.Es. a) $y'sinx+ycosx=2cosx$ b) $\frac{1+y'}{1-y'}=\frac{1-\frac{y}{x}}{1+\frac{y}{x}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

a) $$y'sinx+ycosx=2cosx$$
b) $$\frac{1+y'}{1-y'}=\frac{1-\frac{y}{x}}{1+\frac{y}{x}}$$

These are separable first order differential equations but i don't know where to start. I've tried substituting for u but it doesn't seem to work out.
Thanks

Comment: For a) one could note that $D(y\sin x)=y'\sin x+y\cos x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

1. $$\sin x\frac{dy}{dx}+y\cos x=2\cos x$$
   $$\frac{dy}{dx}+y\cot x=2\cot x$$
2. $$\frac{1+y'}{1-y'}=\frac{1-\frac{y}{x}}{1+\frac{y}{x}}$$
   $$\frac{1+y'}{1-y'}+1=\frac{1-\frac{y}{x}}{1+\frac{y}{x}}+1$$
   $$\frac{2}{1-y'}=\frac{2}{1+\frac{y}{x}}$$ $$1-y'=1+\frac{y}{x}$$
   $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x}$$

Both the above differential equations are in the linear form

Answer (score 0):

For (a).Divide by $\sin x$ to get $y'+y\cot x=2\cot x$.The general method to solve the linear form $$y'+yf=g$$ is to let $F'=f$ and observe that $$g.e^F=y'.e^F+y.f.e^F=(y.e^F)'$$ so $$ y.e^F=K+\int g.e^F$$  with $K$ constant.